# Override initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, initialization, nsmanagedobject

I'm little bit confused with `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`.
According to [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)(Two-Phase Initialization) I should call `super.init` after I initialise all new properties of subclass.
But when I do so with following code I get error:

```
//In subclass of NSManagedObject
init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?, origin: NavCoordinate, destination:NavCoordinate, city: String, averageSpeedKmPH:NSNumber, client:String)
    {
        self.origin = origin
        self.destination = destination
        self.city = city
        self.averageSpeedKmPH = averageSpeedKmPH
        self.client = client
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }
```

The problem is I get error: "Super.init called multiple times in initializer"

If I call `super.init...` first than it is ok.

Also documentation for [initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:) says:

> If you override initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:, you must ensure that you set self to the return value from invocation of super’s implementation, as shown in the following example:

But without any example. 
What is the correct way to override `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to solve to with calling `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` first and then call `setup` on entity. This seems to be best solution because this way you don't break Swift [Two-Phase Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) and support core data undo, redo.

```
let journey = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("JourneyEntity", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Journey
journey.setupJourney(origin, destination: destination, city: city, averageSpeedKmPH: self.user.averageSpeedKmPH, client:client)
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `init(entity entity: NSEntityDescription,
insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?)` says

> You are discouraged from overriding this method—you should instead override awakeFromInsert and/or awakeFromFetch (if there is logic common to these methods, it should be factored into a third method which is invoked from both). If you do perform custom initialization in this method, you may cause problems with undo and redo operations.

The correct way is to override awakeFromInsert instead of init.

Comment: How do I pass parameters to set?

Comment: I didn't scroll and didn't see your parameters.